# Is Dell Bios article on Ubuntu Wiki outdated?

Tags: dell, bios, xps

I came across this "immutable" page on the [wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DellBIOS).

According to this, Dell doesn't support Ubuntu?? Even if they [advertise it preinstalled](http://www.dell.com/us/business/p/xps-13-linux/pd)?

Also, it seems the non-Windows instructions don't match the non-windows installation instructions, [here for example](http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/04/DriverDetails/Product/xps-13-l321x?driverId=2RPM5&osCode=W764&fileId=3123200647&languageCode=en&categoryId=BI).

Am I right in assuming the Dell instructions are the correct ones for Bios updates?

Comment: I can't definitively answer your question , but according to the bottom of the wiki, it was-  "last edited 2013-11-15 05:34:51"

Answer (score 1):

I can only assure you, that the following steps worked for me. This "**What worked for one user on a Dell Inspiron 1525 and Xubuntu, using Wine to extract BIOS image etc**" on the mentioned [wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DellBIOS) is quite similar to my steps:

I've recently updated the BIOS of my Dell Latitude E6500 from version A27 to A29 under Linux Mint 17 KDE (= Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Trusty Tahr) with the CLI and here is what worked very well for me:

1. Download the needed DELL Software `sudo apt-get install firmware-addon-dell smbios-utils wine`
2. Check your BIOS version: `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` My output: `A27`
3. Download your BiosUpdateFile.exe (in my case E6500A29.exe) for your specific device from the [DELL Support Page](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/Products/?IsTag=False&IsInvalidSelection=False&c=us&l=en&s=dhs)
4. Switch to the directory which nests your E6500A29.exe and extract the *.hdr file from it with the command: `wine E6500A29.exe -writehdrfile`
5. Update BIOS: `sudo dellBiosUpdate -u -f E6500A29.hdr`
6. Reboot: `sudo reboot now`
7. Check your BIOS version again: `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` My output: `A29`